# How to test cover with Jasmine an Angular 9 service with window.location.href.substring() and toPromise().then()?

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-jasmine, code-coverage

I'm making some Unit Tests with Jasmine, on my Angular program, but I'm a beginner in it. And I can't cover some parts of my code, even after reading some examples here.

First, here is my UserService :

```
export class UserService {
  user: User;
  role: Role;
  profile: string;
  headers: HttpHeaders;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private resources: Resources) {}

  getUserInit(): Promise<any> {
    let profile: string;
    let headers: HttpHeaders;
    const profilePosition = window.location.href.indexOf('to=');

    if (profilePosition > 0) {
      profile = window.location.href.substring(window.location.href.indexOf('to=') + 3);
    }

    if (profile) {
      headers = new HttpHeaders({
        profile,
        skip: 'true',
      });
    } else {
      headers = new HttpHeaders({
        skip: 'true',
      });
    }

    this.profile = profile;
    this.headers = headers;

    return this.http
      .get<User>(this.resources.connectedUser, { headers })
      .toPromise()
      .then((user) => {
        this.user = user;

        this.role = new Role(
          this.user.profileCode === Resources.MANAGE,
          this.user.profileCode === Resources.NAT,
          this.user.profileCode === Resources.BRA,
          this.user.profileCode === Resources.DPT
        );

        this.user.orgaList = [
          new Branch(1, null, new Department(null)),
          new Branch(2, null, new Department(null))
        ];

        return user;
      });
  }

  getUser() {
    return this.user;
  }

  getRole() {
    return this.role;
  }
}
```

And now, this is my test :

```
describe('UserService', () => {
  let service: UserService;
  let httpTestingController: HttpTestingController;
  let resources: Resources;

  const manageRole = RoleSample.getManageRole();
  const natRole = RoleSample.getNatRole();
  const braRole = RoleSample.getBranchRole();
  const dptRole = RoleSample.getDptRole();

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
      providers: [UserService, Resources],
    });

    service = TestBed.inject(UserService);
    httpTestingController = TestBed.inject(HttpTestingController);
    resources = TestBed.inject(Resources);
  });
 
  it('should create the component', () => {
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();

  });

  it('should test the manager role', () => {
    service.role = new Role(true, false, false, false);
    expect(service.getRole()).toEqual(manageRole);
  });
    
  it("should test user initialization", () => {
    let userPromise = service.getUserInit();

    userPromise.then((user) => {
      expect(service.getUser()).toEqual(user);
    });
  });
});
```

With that, I can't cover those parts (and I would like to cover them) :

1. profile = window.location.href.substring(window.location.href.indexOf('to=') + 3);
2. headers = new HttpHeaders
3. **(u**ser) => {
   **this.user = user;
   this.role = new Role**
4. this.user.orgaList = [
5. return user;
6. getUser()

I guess if I can cover 1 and 3, it could cover them all. But I don't know how to do that. I tried many solutions, with spyOn, but it failed. If someone can explain me how to cover, at least, 1 and 3, I would really thank him.

Edit : as asked in the comments, here is some code (classes needed). I have so much files that I hope I didn't forget any.

```
export class Resources {
  public static MANAGE = 'test-manage';
  public static NAT = 'test-national';
  public static BRA = 'test-branch';
  public static DPT = 'test-department';
  public connectedUser = this.urlBackEnd + '/auth/whoami';
}

export class RoleSample {
  static getManageRole(): Role {
    return new Role(true, false, false, false);
  }

  static getNatRole(): Role {
    return new Role(false, true, false, false);
  }

  static getBranchRole(): Role {
    return new Role(false, false, true, false);
  }

  static getDptRole(): Role {
    return new Role(false, false, false, true);
  }
}

export class Role {
  constructor(
    public manage: boolean,
    public national: boolean,
    public branch: boolean,
    public department: boolean
  ) {}
} 

export class User {
  constructor(
    public username: string,
    public idAgent: number,
    public lastname: string,
    public firstname: string,
    public email: string,
    public profileCode: string,
    public orgaList: Branch[]
  ) {}
}

export class Branch {
  constructor(
    public id: number,
    public code: string,
    public department: Department,
  ) {}
}

export class Department {
  constructor(
    public id: number
  ) {}
}
```

Comment: Please give a [mre], there's a lot missing to be able to run that code locally.

Comment: Also your role tests seem very repetitive, don't they all just test that `getRole` returns the `role` you just set? `role` (and `user`, `profile`) should probably be *private* in `UserService` (and `headers` shouldn't be a property at all).

Comment: I added some code. Hope it's enough. 
You're right about the repetitive roles test. I deleted them (here and in my code) for the moment. Going to improve it next.

Comment: You're not actually *using* the HttpTestingController, please read https://angular.io/guide/http#testing-http-requests

Comment: Thank you. I'm going to read it and correct my mistakes.